# This function can only be invoked from LINQ to Entities. How can I solve this?

Tags: entity-framework, linq, model-view-controller

I can't figure out a way to overcome this, I'm trying to select one item on a dropdown list and on the next one show only the items associated to what I selected previously.

```
var xyz = ViewBag.ID_Cliente = new SelectList(db.Clientes, "ID", "Num_Cliente");

var results = from e in db.Extintores.AsEnumerable()
          where SqlFunctions.StringConvert((double)e.ID_Cliente).Contains(xyz)
          select e.Num_Extintor.ToList();

ViewBag.ID_Extintor = new SelectList(results);
```

Can someone help me?

Comment: I think it could be useful to see where _exaclty_ the error is raised (is this a compiler or runtime error -> stacktrace?) My first guess is that `AsEnumerable()` is wrong here, because `SqlFunctions.StringConvert` is explicitly designed to work in a linq2sql-query (and to be translated into sql). But `AsEnumerable()` materializes the query so it's no longer a sql query, but linq-to-objects..

Comment: Do you have any idea what I can do to achieve my goal? by correcting this or any other solution?

Comment: Did you try to remove `AsEnumerable`? What happened then? Not sure if `Contains` can then be translated to sql.

Comment: Yes, if I remove AsEnumerable it displays an error on the next line. I've also tried == xyz to replace contains but the end game remains the same

Comment: What error do you see though?

Comment: An expection tree may not contain a dynamic operation

Comment: The `AsEnumerable` pulls the entire table (`Extintores`) into memory and then runs LINQ to Objects against it. While you can do that, I doubt it is what you want. If you remove the `(double)` cast and the `AsEnumerable`, what happens _exactly_? Also, is `xyz` definition correct? How do you expect `Contains` to understand a `SelectList`???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your desired action, I would suggest using the fluent Linq syntax and composing your query based on whether a selection has been made or not:

Your "xyz" variable is confusing, what is this meant to hold? From your description it sounds like you would want to have a list of clients, then select a Client ID and use that client ID to filter these Extintores.

```
var selectedClientId = ViewBag.SelectedClientId;

var results = db.Extintores;
if (selectedClientId != null)
    results = results.Where(x => x.ID_Cliente == selectedClientId);

ViewBag.Id_Extintor = new SelectList(results.Select(x => x.Num_Extintor));
```

Frankly using `ViewBag` to relay state between view and controller isn't recommended. `ViewBag` is dynamic, so while it is flexible, it's difficult to assert that the state between requests will be reliable. Instead you should leverage a (view)model between calls. I would look to preserve the data type for your variables in the view bag as much as possible. The "list" of available items (`SelectList`) may be a `SelectList` of strings, but when one is selected, it can be parsed back to the appropriate data type rather than casting to strings in the Linq Queries. The big problem with that casting approach is that you forgo the use of indexes in your database. So if your `ViewBag` has a list of ID_Clients, selecting one client from that list should mark that one SelectedClient ID so we can use that to filter the next level. If you want to leverage a multi-select then you need to store a collection of IDs.